# Boto3 S3 Multipart Download of a Large Byte Range

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a set of 4GB files stored in S3 that I need to extract 1GB sections from. I know that I can accomplish this via a `boto3` S3 ranged get request:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = ''
key = ''
start = 100_0000_000
end = 200_0000_000
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range=f'bytes={start}-{end}')
```

However, this download is slow because I am not taking advantage of S3's [multipart download functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_UsingLargeFiles_section.html). I understand how to perform multipart downloads using `boto3`'s [`s3.Object.download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_file) method, but I can't figure out how to specify an overall byte range for this method call.

When downloading large ranges of a file from S3, what is the fastest and cleanest way to perform multipart downloads? Assume that this is running on an EC2 instance in the same region as the S3 bucket.

Comment: [s3.Object.get](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get) supports a Range parameter.

Comment: @jarmod, does `s3.Object.get` support multipart gets as well?

Comment: `s3.Transfer` doesn't document byte ranges as an allowed option, so unless you find it ihe source code it isn't an option. And if you do find it in the source code, you're accepting the risk that it will be removed without warning.

Comment: You could always implement it youself by running range-based downloads on multiple threads and then combining the result, _but have you verified that it's actually faster?_ As in, have you compared the time to download a 1 GB file using Transfer Manager with downloading that same 1 GB file with `get_object()`? My expectation is that the latter will consume all available bandwidth, so having multiple concurrent downloads would provide a minimal improvement.

Comment: If I understand, you're hoping to download some subset of the object e.g. 50% of a 1GB object and you're hoping to be able to that via multiple, concurrent ranged gets e.g. 5 concurrent, 100MB ranged gets. The boto3 Transfer Manager doesn't support this afaik so you'd probably have to implement your own DIY solution using multiple concurrent threads. Using the s3.Object.get method in each thread would be an option here (though I don't know overall how effective this might be in terms of improved performance).

Comment: @jarmod, yes this is what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: @kdgregory, luckily I'm working on an EC2 instance in the same region as the data so I have a lot of bandwidth available. I've updated the question to reflect this. Right now, a 1.3GB file downloads in 43s using `get_object` and in 3.7s when using a multipart `s3.Object.download_file()`.

Comment: Wow, that's a very significant difference. Thanks for adding that context. Wondering if you can somehow leverage/customize boto's underlying s3transfer module and enhance it to support ranged gets. Would have to be custom code. Or submit a PFR at the boto3 repo.

Comment: Agreed, that's a dramatic difference. So much so that I tried it myself on an `md5.large`, accessing S3 via a Gateway endpoint and writing to the attached instance store And while I didn't see quite as dramatic a difference (5 seconds with `download_file`, 16 with `get_object` to pull a 1GiB object) if you're doing that enough I can see it being worthwhile to run in parallel. Having looked at the internals of `boto3` in the past, I think you'll be better off spinning out multiple Python threads rather than adapting what's already there.

Comment: Incidentally, I also tried processing the `get_object` body using `iter_chunks`, because I thought that the difference might be due to Python memory management. Times were consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a working solution using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I believe it can still be improved. The best approach I found was to set up a thread pool of `s3_client.get_object` calls that have the range parameter specified:

```py
import math
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import boto3

KB = 1024
MB = KB * KB


def calculate_range_parameters(offset, length, chunk_size):
    num_parts = int(math.ceil(length / float(chunk_size)))
    range_params = []
    for part_index in range(num_parts):
        start_range = (part_index * chunk_size) + offset
        if part_index == num_parts - 1:
            end_range = str(length + offset - 1)
        else:
            end_range = start_range + chunk_size - 1

        range_params.append(f'bytes={start_range}-{end_range}')
    return range_params


def s3_ranged_get(args):
    s3_client, bucket, key, range_header = args
    resp = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Range=range_header)
    body = resp['Body'].read()
    return body


def threaded_s3_get(s3_client, bucket, key, offset, length, chunksize=10 * MB):
    args_list = [(s3_client, bucket, key, x) for x in calculate_range_parameters(offset, length, chunksize)]

    # Dispatch work tasks with our client
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        results = executor.map(s3_ranged_get, args_list)

    content = b''.join(results)
    return content


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = ''
key = ''

content = threaded_s3_get(s3, bucket, key, 1 * MB, 101 * MB)
with open('data.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

`calculate_range_parameters` creates a list of range argument inputs given a file offset, length, and chunksize, `s3_ranged_get` wraps the `boto3` s3-client `get_object` method, and `threaded_s3_get` sets up the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. When accessing a 1.3 GB region of data in an open bucket on an in-region r5d.xlarge EC2 instance, this code will download the data in 4.76 seconds. For comparison, using the `boto3`-native multipart download functionality to download the same amount of data under the same conditions takes 3.96 seconds (i.e. my solution takes 1.2x the time of the native solution).

This solution will work for now, but long-term it would be great to see `boto3` support multipart reads of large byte ranges natively.